# Is there a tool for refactoring SQL, a bit like a ReSharper for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

The sort of stuff I'm after right now is quite basic:

- Auto format
- Detect unused variables
- Variable naming convention checking

I wouldn't be surprised if there was a tool available that could handle more complex refactorings such as those found in [Refactoring Databases](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321293533/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1265207525&sr=8-1), but I appreciate that the added complexities introduced by current db structure and data state may prevent many of them.

I suppose I'm after ReSQLer

Comment: An overlooked problem of SQL automatic refactorings is that they don't cover the migration of all the data (e.g. by generating migration scripts) and the incoming dependencies (e.g. JDBC statements of java code).

These are completely necessary to make a SQL refactoring "real" automatic! This complexity is not met by the SQL refactoring tools I know of.

Comment: Completely agree on the incoming dependencies, but I don't see why such a tool couldn't generate some data manipulation statements to go with the schema manipulation ones (e.g. Normalising a single table into two tables, denormalising two tables into one etc).

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is a free tool for SQL Server database development. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JetBrains have just announced 0xDBE - a new IDE for SQL machines.

It's build on the IntelliJ platform, so should have many of the same shortcuts you get in the JetBrains suite of products.

http://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/

Comment: If you signed up for the 0xDBE Beta, they pushed the first beta version out, today

Comment: It's now called DataGrip.

Answer (score 22):

RedGate offers [SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm) and [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm), along with a slew of other [SQL related tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/index.htm). Check out their pages for more info and for a free trial.

Comment: +1 For SQL Refactor - looking at the demo and that seems perfect!

Comment: Just curious, do they allow you to define your own style standards, or must you use their pre-defined set?

Comment: @Philip I believe its customizable up to the extent their options allow. See this screenshot for an example of some options: http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/images/sql_layout.gif

Comment: Note that all of SQL Refactor's functionality has been merged into SQL Prompt as of SQL Prompt version 5, so you can no longer get SQL Refactor directly. [I am Red Gate's Project Manager for SQL Prompt]

Answer (score 9):

There is a free SQL formatting and refactoring add-in for SSMS and VS developed by ApexSQL. I suggest you check these articles before you decide if it's the right tool for you:

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/category/sql-code-refactoring/

Answer (score 5):

I have used Embarcadero Rapid SQL for code formating.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation, but after a bit more than just formatting

Comment: I presume you're talking about http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rapid-sql ? This seems to do more than just formatting, so might give that a whirl later :) I'd +1 again if I could!

Comment: +1'd on Martin's behalf, because he seems like a nice guy, and I like to help nice guys out when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Something like [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm) from RedGate?

Comment: RedGate sponsor the tag `sql-server`, quite funny how this pops up as a question :)

Comment: Huh, a downvote? Take note of the time and date of my answer and then to the accepted answer. It's a slightly cruel vote you've cast here, @downvoter.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Prompt has basic format and beautify functions now, if you don't want to buy both products

The free SSMS Tools Pack supports basic beautify as well I believe
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=3

> Uppercase/Lowercase keywords and
>   proper case Database Object Names. Set
>   all keywords to uppercase or lowercase
>   letters. Custom keywords can be added.
>   Format all database objects to their
>   proper case sensitive name.

Answer (score 2):

I use [SQL Enlight](http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/index.php), which is a fairly inexpensive tool which does autoformatting, validation and refactoring pretty well. (And -- no, I am not affiliated w/ Ubitsoft in any way...)